# Nullable DateTime values from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How do we read integer null values from `SqlDataReader`?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mem_Basic] (
  [Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [Mem_Email]   VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
  [Mem_DOB]     DATE          NULL,
  [Mem_ResPin]  INT           NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

For string and integer I use

```
if (reader.Read() == true)
{
  mb.Mem_Email = reader["Mem_Email"] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["Mem_Email"];
  mb.Mem_ResPin = reader["Mem_ResPin"] as int? ?? default(int);
 }
```

But how do I read the date in same manner from reader?

```
//mb.Mem_DOB = (Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Mem_DOB"]));
```

Comment: i cant't read date value from database of there is know value is there (null value). If there is null i want return null value

Comment: If it's a nullable DateTime in the DB, it should be a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`) in the data access layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mb.Mem_DOB = reader["Mem_DOB"] == DBNull.Value
                 ? (DateTime?) null
                 : (DateTime) reader["Mem_DOB"];
```

The `mb.Mem_DOB` should be declared as a `DateTime?`

Don't use `Convert.ToDateTime`.  The value is *already* a `DateTime`, so just cast it.

Comment: @Matt-shows the error there is no impicit convertion between <null> and System. DateTime

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime? Mem_DOB = null;

mb.Mem_DOB = reader["Mem_DOB"] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Mem_DOB"]);
```

Comment: Does that compile, or do you need `(DateTime?)null`?

Comment: @Parvathiiiii - what is the type of `Mem_DOB`?

Comment: Mem_DOB is a nullable DateTime member of your class `mb` and its also the name of a column in your database table.

Comment: @Corak-[Mem_DOB]     DATE          NULL,

Comment: public DateTime Mem_DOB { get; set; } ya

Comment: `public DateTime? Mem_DOB { get; set; }`  - nullable with the question mark:)

Comment: @JeremyThompson:shows the error there is no impicit convertion between <null> and System. DsteTime

Comment: @Parvathiiiii [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.aspx) can *not* hold a null value. [DateTime?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) can. Notice the question mark at the end. But changing that means, everywhere you use it, you need to check for [HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sksw8094.aspx) and then use the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ydkbatt6.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
mb.Mem_DOB = reader["Mem_DOB"] == System.DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Mem_DOB"]);
```

Comment: `SQLDateTime` for 1753, not DateTime.MinValue as 1/1/0001 as dates before 1753 wont work being reinserted into SQL.

Comment: I asume that `Mem_DOB` is DateTime, not `DateTime?`. In this case we should read it this way and write to database `Null` if `Mem_DOB == DataTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is null or not.

```
int i = reader.GetOrdinal("Mem_DOB")
if( reader.IsDBNull(i))
   mb.Mem_DOB = someDefaultValueforyourdatetime; //assign null of Mem_DOB is nullable
else
   mb.Mem_DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(reader(i));
```

Though instead of using Convert.ToDateTime directly, i would recommend using [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx).

Comment: That will only work if `Mem_DOB` is a **nullable** `DateTime?` field of your class....